# If statement with booleans android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, if-statement, boolean

I have been having a problem with a Boolean in an if statement all day and it is really starting to irritate me now!! I have looked at other Android threads on here and the solutions just don't seem t work.

My code started off like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
public static boolean isSignedIn = false;       

public final static String USERNAME_MESSAGE = "com.example.libnoise.MESSAGE";
Button btnSignIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       


    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(PlayZone.USERNAME_MESSAGE); 

    if(isSignedIn == false))
    {
   btnSignIn.setText("SignIn");
    }
    else
    {       
         btnSignIn.setText(message);
    }        
}
```

Then I had a thought that made it's not like other languages and I only need one "=" sign so I had it as this:

```
    if(isSignedIn = false)
    {
   btnSignIn.setText("SignIn");
    }
    else
    {       
         btnSignIn.setText(message);
    }
```

That didn't work and that's when I started looking online, after finding a previous thread on here  changed it to the following:

```
    if("false".equals(isSignedIn))
    {
   btnSignIn.setText("SignIn");
    }
    else
    {       
         btnSignIn.setText(message);
    }
```

Now that doesn't look right to me in the first place but hoped it would work and it didn't.

As this is the MainActivity it loads first however since I added all this, the app crashes before it will even load when I take out the if statement it work as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: As this is the Main activity, it won't have an intent message when you initially open from launcher

Comment: @cjk in the AVD  it's "Unfortunatley, LibNoise has stopped" In the logCat it has many and the first is "Java.Lang.RuntimeExetption: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.libnoise.MainActivity}: java.lng.NullPointerExecption"

Comment: @ataulm I see when I open it I'm trying to read something fro another activity which I assume then in the eyes of the app doesn't exsist yet?

Comment: Indeed. Each activity is started with an intent, even from the launcher (see your manifest). The launcher doesn't put messages in these intents, but other activities can - so if you enter your main activity from another point in your app (another activity) (which is entirely acceptable) it may have added an `extra` so your usage is fine, as long as you don't expect anything to be there when you open from launcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can simply use

```
if(!isSignedIn)
{
  btnSignIn.setText("SignIn");
}
else
{       
  btnSignIn.setText(message);
}
```

the way you followed is also correct i didn't find any mistake in except you are using extra bracket in condition `if(isSignedIn == false))`

Comment: If this is the corrct answer, then the question is wrong.  This doesn't solve a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Actually FLAG got a value here. So how NullPointerException arise? i gave the answer on the base of provided code

Answer (score 4):

This

```
if (isSignedIn == false)
```

is perfectly correct. (You could also write `if (!isSignedIn)`, but that's just a matter of style.)

Note that, since you never change the value of `isSignedIn` (at least not in the code you have shown us), it will always be `false`.

Answer (score 3):

If statements with boolean are same how you do it in Java, `==` is the right way to compare

The problem in your code is extra bracket

`if (isSignedIn == false)`<strike>`)`</strike>

Comment: But, using `==` is not the right way to compare especially `String`... :)

Comment: Yes for String == and .equal are different, i was talking only about Boolean

Comment: Careful with your caps there. `Boolean` and `boolean` are *not* the same, and the outcome of == with each will sometimes be very different.

Answer (score 2):

Just to deviate from the question, but point out what is possibly your problem, your null pointer could be because you are accessing a UI object that may well not be ready to have it's text set yet.

While some API versions cope fine with what you're doing, I've found many device/API combos simply aren't ready to have anything changed from what's in the xml until onStart. The general guidance is to load data in onCreate, but not start *doing* anything until onStart.